# Framework7 - Cordova - Input Keyboard not working on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, keyboard

I upgraded to latest Xcode and started getting an error whenever I focus on an input field.

It only lets me type 1 character, and then I cannot type anything else (even though the keys 'pressed' animation does work, so the app is not completely frozen), unless I switch to another input and then back to the last input, which is awful.

I get the following in console, but I'm not really sure what this could mean, or which one could be the actual issue related to not letting me type more than 1 character.

I saw other threads but most of them don't report a failure in functionality nor anything similar to this very specific issue.

> 2018-11-23 20:02:13.037217-0600 TeeMovil[20553:4852294] API error:
>   <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x14fd18030; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer =
>   > returned 0 width, assuming
>   UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric 2018-11-23 20:02:13.038200-0600
>   TeeMovil[20553:4852294] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView:
>   0x14fd18030; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = >
>   returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric 2018-11-23
>   20:03:05.732995-0600 TeeMovil[20553:4852294] [LayoutConstraints]
>   Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one
>   of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.   Try
>   this:         (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
>   don't expect;         (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint
>   or constraints and fix it.    (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone faces similar issues, it was a problem with css.
Specifically these modifiers, so I had to remove them:

```
  -webkit-touch-callout:none;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -khtml-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select:none;
  user-select:none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: I have the exact same Issue right now, did it cause any wild behavior after removing them?

Comment: Not that I noticed at least.

Comment: Your solution worked as a charm. Thank you!!!